# ImportError: cannot import name 'NA' from 'pandas._libs.missing'

Tags: pandas, importerror

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("txt.csv")
```

gives me an error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'NA' from 'pandas._libs.missing'

I have traced the directory for _libs and still haven't resolved what to do.

I have also tried to uninstall and install pandas back again but `pip install pandas` gives me the following message:

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError:
>   [WinError 5] Access is denied:
>   'C:\Users\Ana\Anac1\Lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\hashtable.cp37-win_amd64.pyd'
>   Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: These are 2 different problems, you should have split it in 2 questions.

Answer (score 1):

The second one is because your user is not allowed to install packages for the system python. You can install it only locally with `pip install --user pandas`.

The first one would require to look at the content of the file. You may try also to set the parameter `na_values=[]` in other to NOT interpret `NA` as the null value.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Thank you so much! I fixed it with pip install --user pandas.